# Adding a checkbox to the list of checkbox and label

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

```
<table style="width: 98%; height: 100%; text-align: left">
    <tr>     
        <td valign="top">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="c1" runat="server" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Id" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
               OnDataBound="cblAvailableWidgetSelector_DataBound">
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            <label runat="server" id="lblMessage" style="padding: 3px;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here, I get the out as list of checkbox and label attached to it.

Example: I get,

```
Checkbox Item1
Checkbox Item2
Checkbox Item3
```

But I want,

```
Checkbox Checkbox Item1
Checkbox Checkbox Item2
Checkbox Checkbox Item3
```

I am using a checkbox listitem, but How can I get the output as desired.

In the code file,

```
DataTable dt = //datatable, which I get
            c1.DataSource = dt;
            c1.DataBind();
```

So, I get the checkbox list and a label with values, but I want to add 1 more checkbox to this list. How can I do that ?

**Update**

Trying to use this,

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="CheckBoxRepeater">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="c1" OnDataBinding="c1_DataBound"   runat="server" Checked="<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Id")) %>" />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server"  />
                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"  style="padding: 3px;" Text="<%# Eval("Title") %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

But still it is not working.

```
Error: The server tag is not well formed.
```

Comment: Your first column is a checkboxlist not checkbox !!

Answer (score 0):

CheckBoxList does not allow you custom templating, so it is too limited to achieve what you are trying to do. But this should be very easy to imitate with repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="CheckBoxRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Checked="<%# Eval("BoolProperty1") %>" />
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Checked="<%# Eval("BoolProperty2") %>" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("TextProperty") %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Make sure to use Bind instead of Eval if you need two-way binding.

Comment: @user1989, do you really have boolean ids? That does not make a lot of sense to me. Anyway, your problem is with quotes, should be something like `Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Id")) %>'`, notice single quotes around `<%# %>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
Checked="<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Id")) %>"
```

Try this:

```
Checked="<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval('Id')) %>"
```

ASP.NET gets picky with the quotation marks in a render block. You need to alternate - one set is double, one set is single quotes.